# Are Values of the HTML lang Attribute Case-sensitive?

Tags: xml, html

`<html lang="en-ca">` vs `<html lang="en-CA">` vs other variants:

- `EN-ca`
- `en-Ca`

To modern user agents, are all of these interpreted the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the lang attribute is not affected by the case of the language. From what I have seen,`<html lang="en-ca">` is the same as `<html lang="EN-CA">`, but for safety, you should probably just use `<html lang="en-ca">`.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this spec sheet saying they are not case sensitive:
https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/types.html#h-6.8

> 6.8 Language codes
>
> The value of attributes whose type is a language code ( [%LanguageCode](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/sgml/dtd.html#LanguageCode) in the DTD) refers to a language code as specified by [[RFC1766]](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/references.html#ref-RFC1766), section 2. For information on specifying language codes in HTML, please consult the section on [language codes](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/struct/dirlang.html#langcodes). Whitespace is not allowed within the language-code.
>
> Language codes are [case-insensitive](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40-971218/types.html#case-insensitive).